# What shortcode should I use for <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>

Tags: customization, search, search-engines

I have the same issue as the question posted here :

[Is there a way to stop WP editor deleting <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143459/is-there-a-way-to-stop-wp-editor-deleting-gcsesearchbox-only-gcsesearchbox/143463?noredirect=1#comment209188_143463)

I have created a custom-function.php file where I put the shortcode required. It works for the search box.

However, I would now like to do the same for the searchresults code `gcse:searchresults-only</gcse:searchresults-only>`. I tried editing the shortcode above but that doesn't work.

What I want is have the search results appear in the same page as the search box, not in a separate one which the current shortcode does.

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Create different shortcode for different tag you need? Exactly same principle applies.

Comment: How did you edit the shortcode? Post your code. For the record (and maybe this is confusing you) my shortcode, from the question you reference, doesn't do anything but `echo` a single line of markup. It does not provide an actual search box not does it process the search. Some other code, almost certainly Javascript, does that.